# AutoGrad Hessian in custom loss function in XGboost takes very long time

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, boosting, hessian

I am using the autograd package and generating the hessian of my loss function using that package as part of my custom loss function XGB model. However, it takes an extremely long time to iterate through the gradient descent model. I am unable to do an analytical version of my loss function due to various reasons but is there any other way to make the model train faster ?

Comment: Just to state the obvious: is the implementation correct? How does it compare against standard numerical differentiation? That said, I suspect that you might get some advice on the [SciComp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: THe implementation is pretty trivial. I just provide the loss function to the function and pass in the actual predictions.     
      hess_f = hessian(self.loss_function)
        return  hess_f(preds)